# TV antenna problem: Transmission line problem

Tags: electromagnetism, transmission-line

I have to solve the following problem:
A TV antenna lead-in wire 10cm long has a characteristic impedance of 250 \$\Omega\$
and is open-circuited at its end. If the line operates at 400 MHz, determine it's input impedance.

I came up with a solution to this problem, but I'm not sure it's right. I have some doubts. I don't think I'm using the right equation for \$Z_{in}\$ I don't know how to pick if I should use the lossy or lossless \$Z_{in}\$ equation.

Lossless Case: \$Z_{in}\$ \$=\$ \$Z_o\frac{Z_L + jZ_o\tan(\beta L)}{Z_o + jZ_L\tan(\beta L)}\$

Lossy Case: \$Z_{in}\$ \$=\$ \$Z_o\frac{Z_L + Z_o\tanh(\gamma L)}{Z_o + Z_L\tanh(\gamma L)}\$

My Solution:

Since we are given that the it's open circuited choosing the lossless case we get the following simplification because \$Z_L =\infty \$

\$ Z_{oc} = \frac{Z_o}{jtan(\beta L)}\$

So we need to calculate \$\beta\$ This could be calculated by using the following formula:

\$\beta = \frac{\omega}{u}\$

We know \$\omega = 2\pi f = 2\pi(400*10^6)\$ and with that we can find the speed assuming air is free space so therefore u = c, where c is the speed of light.

\$\therefore \beta = \frac{2\pi(400*10^6)}{c} = \frac{8\pi}{3}\$

\$ Z_{oc} = \frac{Z_o}{jtan(\frac{8\pi}{3} 0.10)} \approx -j225.10\$

Does this answer make sense? This is my first time dealing with Transmission Line Equations, so I'm not so sure.

Comment: I fear this question is not valid?... we first need the parameters for the RF wire, for defining the transmission line parameters. Once doing that, you fill in the equations (lossless or lossy) and solve the impedance for a given L.....

Comment: Agree, I think there is not evough information to usefully answer the question.